# How to reverse category order on clustered bar chart in PowerPoint using Python-pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm trying to generate a clustered bar chart using Python-pptx. However the order of categories that appear on the chart is the opposite of that in data table.

In PowerPoint, check on 'Categories in reverse order' in category axis options would solve the problem. I've searched for a while but can't find the equivalent property in Python code. Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this feature exists. Can you not reverse the order of your table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API doesn't directly support this feature yet as @Boosted_d16 noted. It seems this can be accomplished fairly trivially using a workaround function. First, we need to identify the differences in the underlying XML, and then manipulate our output XML accordingly.

Here is the relevant portion for the `BAR_CLUSTERED` chart as defaults from `pptx`, this is referring to its `category_axis`:

```xml
  <c:catAx>
    <c:axId val="-2068027336"/>
    <c:scaling>
      <c:orientation val="maxMin"/>
    </c:scaling>
```

If we modify that manually in PowerPoint application to *Categories in reverse order*, it will look like this instead:

```xml
  <c:catAx>
    <c:axId val="-2068027336"/>
    <c:scaling>
      <c:orientation val="minMax"/>
    </c:scaling>
```

So the only change is to the `/c:scaling/c:orientation[0]` element, which needs to be given a value of **`"minMax"`** instead of **`"maxMin"`**. We can do this by passing reference to the axis to a helper function, like this:

```
def set_reverse_categories(axis):
    """
    workaround function that replicates the "Categories in Reverse Order" UI option in PPT
    """
    ele = axis._element.xpath(r'c:scaling/c:orientation')[0]
    ele.set("val", "maxMin")
```

## Example output

The chart with category axis reversed is on the left, the default output is on the right.

[image]

## Example usage

This program will create a presentation with the two slides in above screenshot. Note that you may need to change the layout index.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pandas import DataFrame as DF
p = Presentation()
# Create some data to be used in the chart
series_names = ["A","B","C","D"]
cat_names = ["cat 1"]
data = {
        cat_names[0]: [.10, .20, .30, .40]
        }
df = DF(data, series_names, cat_names)
cd = CategoryChartData()
cd.categories = df.index
for name in df.columns:
    data = df[name]
    cd.add_series(name, data, '0%')

layout = p.slide_layouts[6] # MODIFY AS NEEDED, 6 is the index of my "Blank" slide template.

# Create two charts, one reversed and one not reversed on the Category Axis
for reverse in (True, False):
    slide = p.slides.add_slide( layout )
    shape = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED, 0, 0, 9143301, 6158000, cd) 
    cht = shape.chart
    plot = cht.plots[0]
    plot.has_data_labels = False
    if reverse:
        set_reverse_categories(cht.category_axis)

p.save(r'c:\debug\ppt_chart.pptx')
```

**NOTE:** This also affects the chart visually w/r/t "Crosses At", and the horizontal/value axis now appears at the top of the chart. You'll need to adjust this separately. The pptx API doesn't directly support this, but it can also be implemented via workaround function:

```
def set_axis_crosses_at(cht, index, position_at):
    """
    cht: chart
    index: string 'value' or 'category' -- which axis to be adjusted
    position_at: 'max, 'autoZero', or int representing category index for Crosses At.
    """
    ns = "{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart}"
    axes = {'value': cht.value_axis, 'category': cht.category_axis}
    axis = axes.get(index, None)
    if not axis: 
        return
        # probably should throw error here
    ax_ele = axis._element
    crosses = ax_ele.xpath(r'c:crosses')[0]
    scaling = ax_ele.xpath(r'c:scaling')[0]
    if position_at in ('max', 'autoZero'):
        crosses.set('val', f'{position_at}')
        return
    elif isinstance(position_at, int):
        ax_ele.remove(crosses)
        if len(ax_ele.xpath(r'c:auto')) > 0:
            ax_ele.remove(ax_ele.xpath(r'c:auto')[0])
        # crossesAt:
        if len(ax_ele.xpath(r'c:crossesAt')) == 0:
            crossesAt = etree.SubElement(ax_ele, f'{ns}crossesAt')
        else:
            crossesAt = ax_ele.xpath(r'c:crossesAt')[0]
        crossesAt.set('val', f'{position_at}')
```

## Example Output:

[image]

Comment: Holy Moly! Will give this a try now :)

Comment: This works well. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you!

Comment: Hey @david, what value do i need to put in `position_at` if i want the axis after the D bar i.e. at the end?

Answer (score 1):

No support for this feature yet.

Theres a ticket for it on the repo: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/517

Comment: good catch with the open ticket. FWIW I've been developing in pptx for about a year now and my approach is as you suggest in the comments: simply reverse the order of the table.

Comment: using this feature would reverse the order of the colours automatically, whereas reversing the order of the table wouldnt do anything about the colours.

Comment: reverse the order of the *data* before you instantiate the ChartData in PPT. Then you do not need to subsequently worry about reversing the order of the colors.

Comment: on a bar chart, powerpoint assigns the 1st colour in your pallete at the bottom, what if you want the 1st colour to be at the top? setting reverse categories to true would do this for you. Reversing the table before you insert it to the chart won't.

Comment: you're simply going to need to assign the colors individually. Unfortunate, but that's the way the package is currently implemented. There may be a workaround, let me play with it.

Comment: of course you can do it yourself but allowing powerpoint's rendering engine to do it automatically is much better.